# Insert a whitespace after comma, period and other punctuation marks

Tags: java, regex, string

In Java, what is the best way to fix the missing whitespace after some punctuation marks like:

```
, . ; : ? !
```

For example:

```
String example = "This is!just an:example,of a string,that needs?to be fixed.by inserting:a whitespace;after punctuation marks.";
```

The output should be:

```
"This is! just an: example, of a string, that needs? to be fixed. by inserting: a whitespace; after punctuation marks."
```

It is clear that this does not work:

```
example = example.replaceAll("[,.!?;:]", " ");
```

So I'm looking for a solution waiting for your help.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add `$0` to your replace expression, you can use:

```
example = example.replaceAll("[,.!?;:]", "$0 ");
```

It will replace your matched regex with that content plus a space.

Btw, if you want ensure that you don't have multiple whitespaces you can do:

```
example = example.replaceAll("[,.!?;:]", "$0 ").replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

Will convert:

> This is!just an:example,of a string,that needs?to be fixed.by
>   inserting:a whitespace;after punctuation marks.;

To:

> This is! just an: example, of a string, that needs? to be fixed. by
>   inserting: a whitespace; after punctuation marks.

Comment: With this solution, I have to remove possible double spaces after replaceAll.

Comment: @MariaH I edited the answer for removing posible multiple spaces. Keep in mind that that answer followed your criteria. If you want to try a different criteria I support guys' answers

Comment: After this fixing I have to check double withespaces anyway. So, for me this is the best and most simple solution. Thanks!!

Comment: @MariaH glad you like it

Answer (score 9):

You can use a combination of [**Positive Lookbehind** and **Negative Lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
example = example.replaceAll("(?<=[,.!?;:])(?!$)", " ");
```

**Explanation**:

The Positive Lookbehind asserts at the position that follows any of the select punctuation. The use of the Negative Lookahead says, at this position ( *end of the string* ), the following can not match.

```
(?<=           # look behind to see if there is:
  [,.!?;:]     #   any character of: ',', '.', '!', '?', ';', ':'
)              # end of look-behind
(?!            # look ahead to see if there is not:
  $            #   before an optional \n, and the end of the string
)              # end of look-behind
```

[**Working Demo**](http://ideone.com/9Nbf69)

Comment: Doesn't work with number like `1,200 1.200` or `...`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this with look ahead assertion to prevent adding extra space to the empty space, and match all the non character and add space after them.:

**solution:**

```
     String example = "This is!just an:example,of a string,that needs?to be fixed.by inserting:a whitespace;after punctuation marks.";
     example = example.replaceAll("(?!\\s)\\W", "$0 ");
     System.out.println(example);
```

**result:**

```
This is! just an: example, of a string, that needs? to be fixed. by inserting: a whitespace; after punctuation marks.
```

Comment: You don't need groups if you aren't going to use them

Comment: @Fede it is a look ahead assertion to prevent empty space to be added another space.

Comment: oops! Sorry... someone needs glasses lol. Thanks to point that